# Highcharts missing bars when running through PhantomJS

Tags: javascript, svg, highcharts, phantomjs

I try to generate SVG without using the highcharts-convert.js script:

```
var page = require('webpage').create();
var fs = require('fs');

page.open('http://webtronaut.org/graph122234.html', function() {

  var svg = page.evaluate(function() {
    return($('#highcharts-0').html());
  });

  console.log(svg);
  phantom.exit();

});
```

My command line looks like this: `phantomjs runit.js > test.svg`

The resulting graph SVG (test.svg) should look like this: http://jsfiddle.net/rj3appzz/5/

With PhantomJS the axes look fine, but the bars are missing.

When I compare the SVG code from PhantomJS with the one from the browser, there is one striking difference:
The *transform* parameter from **g** path in the browser's SVG for one bar looks like this:
`translate(645,330) rotate(90) scale(-1,1) scale(1 1)`.
The parameter from PhantomJS looks like this:
`translate(39,317) rotate(90) scale(-1,1) scale(1 0.001)`

There seems to be some scaling issue? Maybe Highcharts misses some size information from PhantomJS?

Comment: Please don't use "shortened" links. If you want to hide/remove the original url at a later date, you can either include all relevant information or delete the question. Related meta-post: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/257936/auto-expand-shortened-urls

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was because of the Highcharts animation when the bars are initialized.

Actually I had the animation disabled in the chart configuration, like:

```
    $('#container').highcharts({
    chart: {
        type: 'bar',
        animation: false
    },
```

But this seems not to be enough. The animation must be disabled explicitly for the chart type:

```
    plotOptions: {
        bar: {
            animation: false,
            enableMouseTracking: false
        }
    }
```

Comment: Couldn't you just wait until the animation is finished?

Comment: what would be the advantage over disabling the animation?

Comment: I'm not familiar with highcharts that well, but it seems that you need to change the page script to achieve this. Simple waiting doesn't require page manipulation.